# How do I row-shift database table contents up or down without modifying primary key IDs?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table where some data between row 29 through row 42 were accidentally off by 1. It's a pain to modify foreign key values to point to the correct primary key IDs.

I would like to know how to row-shift the contents up or down without touching the primary key IDs. I would like to not change the primary key IDs, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Row-Shifting Database Table Row Contents Downwards

Shift the row contents up/down to “bubble” the contents. This is the downwards script. When row-shifting downwards, row 42 will loop back into row 29. Edit the script a bit to suit your needs.

```
# Works and tested in MySQL 5.
# Assuming we are row shifting downwards from row 29 to row 42.
# "counter" is the starting index row of where to start row shifting.

DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mysp //
CREATE PROCEDURE mysp()
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter INT;
    DECLARE startIndex INT;
    DECLARE endIndex INT;
    SET startIndex = 29;
    SET endIndex = 42;
    SET counter = startIndex;

    UPDATE
        yourTable t1 INNER JOIN yourTable t2
        ON (t1.id, t2.id) 
        IN ((startIndex,endIndex),(endIndex,startIndex))
    SET
        t1.column1 = t2.column1;
        # Add your additional columns here.

    label1: WHILE counter < endIndex-1 DO
        UPDATE
            yourTable t1 INNER JOIN yourTable t2
            ON (t1.id, t2.id) 
            IN ((counter+1,endIndex),(endIndex,counter+1))
        SET
            t1.column1 = t2.column1;
            # Add your additional columns here.

        SET counter = counter + 1;
    END WHILE label1;
END; //

CALL mysp() //

DELIMITER ;
```

### Row-Shifting Database Table Row Contents Upwards

This is the row-shifting upwards script. When row-shifting upwards, row 29 will loop back into row 42.

```
# Works and tested in MySQL 5.
# Assuming we are row shifting upwards from row 42 to row 29.
# "counter" is the starting index row of where to start row shifting.

DELIMITER //

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS mysp //
CREATE PROCEDURE mysp()
BEGIN
    DECLARE counter INT;
    DECLARE startIndex INT;
    DECLARE endIndex INT;
    SET startIndex = 29;
    SET endIndex = 42;
    SET counter = endIndex;

    UPDATE
        yourTable t1 INNER JOIN yourTable t2
        ON (t1.id, t2.id) 
        IN ((startIndex,endIndex),(endIndex,startIndex))
    SET
        t1.column1 = t2.column1;
        # Add your additional columns here.

    label1: WHILE counter > startIndex DO
        UPDATE
            yourTable t1 INNER JOIN yourTable t2
            ON (t1.id, t2.id) 
            IN ((counter-1,startIndex),(startIndex,counter-1))
        SET
            t1.column1 = t2.column1;
            # Add your additional columns here.

        SET counter = counter - 1;
    END WHILE label1;
END; //

CALL mysp() //

DELIMITER ;
```